# Composer does not recognize enabled extension ext-curl

Tags: php, curl, composer-php

I have a weird problem. I run on arch-linux and have enabled the curl extension, but my composer installation doesn't recognize the curl extension or at least doesn't list it as installed extension. When I run `php -m` I get:

```
[PHP Modules]
...
curl
...
```

But if I run `composer show --platform` it doesn't list the extension.
I can't install any composer libraries which require ext-curl :( and I can't find out what is wrong with my system. Do you have any idea?

Edit: Thanks to the comments I was able to solve the problem by using `php /usr/bin/composer` instead of `composer` (which works well with an alias). But this is still a small hack since it should work directly with the executable provided by the archlinux repository.

Comment: make sure you don't have a sepreate command line `ini` file.  Sometimes it's named `cli-php.ini`,  Basically there can be a `.ini` file for Apache and different one for the command line (CLI).  You may have enabled it only on Apache, and composer runs in the command line.  So in effect it's still not enabled for composer, even though you enabled it for Apache.  (that's my "default" answer at least).

Comment: Does `php /usr/local/bin/composer show --platform` shows `ext-curl`?

Comment: @rob006 you are right using php /bin/composer show --platform it lists ext-curl. Does that mean the composer binary uses another php.ini file as ArtisticPhoenix suggested?

Comment: What do you get when you run `which php`? What platform are you having this problem on?

Comment: @yivi I am running on arch-linux and `which php` gives me /usr/bin/php

Comment: @blacktemplar Is that all you had to do? I have the same issue, also on Arch (actually Antergos), and cannot get ext-curl to show either way. Yet curl is there for php -m. And visibly enabled in phpinfo(). Trying to install the php-stripe library barfs every time.

Comment: In case anyone else is getting this funkiness, it can be solved by adding an ignore switch to the composer command, eg composer update --ignore-platform-reqs